# How to remove hiding effect in transition?

Tags: css

I have problem with my links in navbar above 768px.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .NavLinks {
        width: 60%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .NavLinks {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: #2980b9;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform .5s ease-in;
    }
    .NavLinks li {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .Burger {
        display: block;
    }
}

.NavLinksActive {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

When I minimalize my window above 768px I see my navbar hide, after that all is awright, but this effect is not good. How can I remove this effect? I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: add your html code -- i think you have setting possition and @media

Comment: move this line `transition: transform .5s ease-in;` to after the element has been clicked

Comment: Add `transform: unset` to your non-mobile view

Comment: This is react app and add transition to non-mobile not working.